# Default relate to field in meetings module

Tags: sugarcrm, sugarbean

In the sugarcrm old version. there is a advance search in the meetings module. in that the relate to field (drop-down) is always defaulted to account. (field name is parent_name_advanced or parent_type)

So if we do search by opps or tasks or any other module ...it always default to Accounts..Does anyone shed some light as to how to change this? The result display in the listview but then again the dropdown is defaulted to Account.. How to work around this problem?

Comment: What version specifically? This sounds like a bug, a customization of the `parent_type_display` dropdown list, or of the meetings module's `parent_type` field.

Comment: i think its 6.5 or 6.4...yes i think i need to customize it. But need somewhere to start. I was thinking of unsetting the $dictionary variable in the ext and then point to a custom function. But again this is not just a dropdown ...its a related to field.

Comment: Sounds like a bug that might be resolved by upgrading. Otherwise... the options in the Related To module selector are driven by the dropdown menu `parent_type_display` so you could try modifying that to place an empty option before it, i.e. `parent_type_display = array(''=>'','option1=>'Option 1'),`

Comment: YEs that works but..Thanks. What i am after is actually is updating the parent_type_advanced value to request variable($_request['parent_name_advanced']).. So that if i select opportunities then atleast the dropdown value should remain to opportunities. It looks bit unprofessional that I select opportunities in advance search and then it default to nothing..